# How do I get the count of null value columns per row in a return set?

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a query which will return me an extra column at the end of my current query which is the count of all columns within the return set which contain a null column. For example:

```
Col 1 - Col 2 - Col 3
A       B       0
A       NULL    1
NULL    NULL    2
```

Is there a simple way to get this return set based on the row values rather than having to requery all the criteria which fetches the original rows?

Answer (score 3):

Ugly solution:

```
select Col1, Col2,
       case when Col1 is null then 1 else 0 end
     + case when Col2 is null then 1 else 0 end
     as Col3
from (

select 'A' as Col1, 'B' as Col2
union select 'A', NULL
union select NULL, NULL

) z
```

This returns

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
NULL NULL 2
A    NULL 1
A    B    0
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has a function NVL2() which makes this easy.

```
select col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       ...
        NVL2(col1,0,1)
       +NVL2(col2,0,1)
       +NVL2(col3,0,1) coln
from   whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) - count(ColumnName) as NumberOfNulls from yourTable
```

returns number of nulls in specific column. if you do this for every column you can get that data.

Answer (score 1):

As in a similar post, SQL is not very suited to work across different columns within a row, but muach better on working across rows.

I'd suggest to turn the table into 'individual' facts about a row, e.g.

```
select <key>, col1 as value From aTable
UNION
select <key>, col2 as value From aTable
UNION
... and so on for the other columns to be summed.
```

This can be turned into a view i.e.

```
create view aView as (select as above).
```

Then the correct answer is just

```
select key, count(*)
from aView
where value is null
Group By key
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table TEST
(
  a VARCHAR2(10),
  b VARCHAR2(10),
  c VARCHAR2(10)
);

insert into TEST (a, b, c)
values ('jas', 'abhi', 'shail');
insert into TEST (a, b, c)
values (null, 'abhi', 'shail');
insert into TEST (a, b, c)
values ('jas', null, 'shail');
insert into TEST (a, b, c)
values ('jas', 'abhi', null);
insert into TEST (a, b, c)
values ('jas', 'abhi', 'abc|xyz');
insert into TEST (a, b, c)
values ('jas', 'abhi', 'abc|xyz');
insert into TEST (a, b, c)
values ('jas', 'abhi', 'abc|xyz');
insert into TEST (a, b, c)
values (null, 'abhi', 'abc|xyz');
commit;

select sum(nvl2(a,null,1)),sum(nvl2(b,null,1)),sum(nvl2(c,null,1))  from test 
where a is null 
or b is null
or c is null
order by 1,2,3
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to add an explanation to the code, as it will be helpful for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

If there isnt a very good reason you need to do this in the SQL, you should just do a for loop through the result set and count the NULL vlues then.

The cost goes from n^n to n..

Comment: @Alexander, 
The runtime cost in terms of cpu cycles might come down, but the developer/maintainer cost in terms of understanding the code goes up.  _If_ it's database logic, I suggest keeping it in the DB.

Comment: @AJ, It's not database logic, it's model logic. I would keep it in the model. But I realise that someone with such a funky implementation as this maybe doesnt use MVC, so that may be a moot point. Oh and how can you say that that SQL is understandable :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(
    col1 nchar(10) NULL,
    col2 nchar(10) NULL,
    col3  AS (case when col1 IS NULL then (1) else (0) end+case when col2 IS NULL then (1) else (0) end)
)
```

It is not a pretty solution, but should work.

If you are dealing with a big number of columns and many of them you expect to be NULL then you could use [sparse columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) (available in SQL Server 2008). It will be optimised for NULL and it can automatically generate XML representation for each row of data in the table.