# Completion Bar for Form Registration in Struts2 Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, hibernate, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am trying to implement a web application using Struts 2, Hibernate 3, and the Struts 2 jQuery plugin progress bar and other widgets.

(http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)

I have a Registration form where I need to show the "% of Form Completion".

```
<sj:progressbar id="progressbarchange" value="21"  onChangeTopics="progressbarchangetopic" cssClass="progressbar"/>
```

I've put above code to instantiate the progress bar in the JSP.

In the "value" field I have hard coded "21", but I want to put the value which I want to  extract from a session variable in the action class. i.e., `"#session.progressvarible"`

`"#session.progressvarible"` is the value I get by calculating the number of columns for a particular record for  **NOT NULL COLUMNS**  and depending upon the value I will set the progress completion in the bar.

I also need to store this Completion Percentage because there are some fields in the form which can be skipped for that moment, so this completion rate has to be displayed whenever user logs in to his home page.

My question is how do I write the query or criteria or whatever, in Hibernate so I can get the count of the NOT NULL columns, for example:

```
select no of columns from table1 which are NOT NULL for the student id=101.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is--are you having a problem with Hibernate, or the progress bar?

Comment: Probably need a native query. If you're going to do that then creating a view in the db would probably be best, for sql solutions see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173745/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-null-value-columns-per-row-in-a-return-set It sounds like you just want it for a known table, so a Java solution could go a couple ways. Probably not needing this service for everything you could just make a method in your entity which checks for null and produces a sum. If you do have many entities you would wish to do this for, then apply the same solution using reflection.

Comment: I justt want to know if there is way to get the number of columns for particular record . say-"studentID-501", which are not null. ? and put that ina session variable to use it how ever i can...if there is any such query please lemme know...and how can i use it using "criteria" ?

Comment: check this out....i agree u can get the desired NOT NULL COLUMN COUNT but...what if there are a 100 or for that matter,a 1000 columns ?,,u can write a query specifying each and every col name in the query given in this link can we ?...is there any smart way to achieve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173745/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-null-value-columns-per-row-in-a-return-set?lq=1